# Ruby - How to execute methods in a loop from an array of of method names

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

I'm fairly new to Ruby and rails so I'm not quite sure how to do things "the right way" but I have several methods from Rspec (get, post, put, delete) that I would like to pass into an array so I can loop over them to execute the same code each time.
I thought that'd be fairly easy but I can't figure out how to do it.

Does anyone know if that's possible, good practice, and how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'].each {|m| obj.send(m) }
```

I see things done this way frequently in Ruby projects.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use `%w(get post put delete).each...`

Comment: ok, I was doing `m.send` and not `obj.send(m)`. I'm gonna look into this. Thank you :)

Comment: My pleasure, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Message
    def method1
      #something
    end

    def method2
      #something
    end   
  end

  message = Message.new
  methods = [ 'method1', 'method2' ]

  methods.each{ |method| message.send(method) }
```

or you can use symbols instead string when you declare your methods because is more idiomatic

It's also best practice to use public_send instead of send, unless you're actually trying to call private methods.